# Producing summary for gradients via cloud TPU's host_call_fn()?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard, google-cloud-tpu

My understanding is that host_call and host_call_fn() transfer stats from the TPU to the host. However, the instructions are not very clear on how to generate summary for anything non-scalar.

For example, I've tried to modify the official mnist_tpu.py to produce a summary for the gradients produced during training. The model_fn() is where the changes are added:

```
...
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate)
if FLAGS.use_tpu:
  optimizer = tf.contrib.tpu.CrossShardOptimizer(optimizer)

grads = optimizer.compute_gradients(loss)
train_op = optimizer.apply_gradients(grads, global_step)

if not FLAGS.skip_host_call:
    def host_call_fn(gs, loss, lr, grads):
        gs = gs[0]
        with summary.create_file_write(FLAGS.model_dir).as_default():
            summary.scalar('loss', loss[0], step=gs)
            summary.scalar('learning_rate', lr[0], step=gs)

            for index, grad in enumerate(grads):
                summary.histogram('{}-grad'.format(grads[index][1].name),
                        grads[index])

            return summary.all_summary_ops()

    gs_t = tf.reshape(global_step, [1])
    loss_t = tf.reshape(loss, [1])
    lr_t = tf.reshape(learning_rate, [1])
    grads_t = grads
    host_call = (host_call_fn, [gs_t, loss_t, lr_t, grads_t])
return tf.contrib.tpu.TPUEstimatorSpec(
    mode=mode,
    loss=loss,
    train_op=train_op
    )
....
```

Unfortunately, the addition above doesn't seem to do the trick as with the histogram generation during CPU-based training. Any idea how to properly generate histogram on non-scalar tensors?

Answer (score 1):

The arguments to host_call_fn [must be tensors](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/official/utils/accelerator/tpu.py#L41). The problem is that grads is a pair of gradient tensors and variables. You should extract out the variable name prior to passing it to host_call_fn and just pass in the gradient tensors. One way to get this to work is to change the arguments of host_call_fn to **kwargs where the keyword argument name is the variable name, and pass a dictionary as the tensor list instead.